# Geting files and directories on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, file, directory

I'd like to put in and read files and directories by "drag and drop" on HTML. But I simply can't do it.

By using the code below, I can only get the files in one directory. But I'd like to get both files in directories and files not in directories at the same time by "drag and drop".

```
<input id='directory_drop' type='file' webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```